# Logger for a Game Engine

Tags: c++, logging

So I'm making a logger for a program and it has 6 levels increasing severity and things I don't think its as memory efficient as it could be but I'm just getting into c++ and memory coding. I feel like if I want to put it in a file I cant view it with a text editor using something like JSON or XML.

This is the code in question

````
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

enum class LogLevel { GREY, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW, ORANGE, RED };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LogLevel level) {
    switch (level) {
    case LogLevel::GREY:
        os << "GREY";
        break;
    case LogLevel::BLUE:
        os << "BLUE";
        break;
    case LogLevel::GREEN:
        os << "GREEN";
        break;
    case LogLevel::YELLOW:
        os << "YELLOW";
        break;
    case LogLevel::ORANGE:
        os << "ORANGE";
        break;
    case LogLevel::RED:
        os << "RED";
        break;
    default:
        os << "UNKNOWN";
        break;
    }
    return os;
}


class Logger {
private:
    std::ofstream logFile;

    std::string getTimestamp() {
        std::time_t now = std::time(nullptr);
        struct tm timeInfo;
        localtime_s(&timeInfo, &now);

        char timestamp[20];
        std::strftime(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeInfo);
        return timestamp;
    }

    std::string getColorCode(LogLevel level) {
        switch (level) {
        case LogLevel::GREY:
            return "\033[90m"; // Grey
        case LogLevel::BLUE:
            return "\033[94m"; // Blue
        case LogLevel::GREEN:
            return "\033[92m"; // Green
        case LogLevel::YELLOW:
            return "\033[93m"; // Yellow
        case LogLevel::ORANGE:
            return "\033[91m"; // Orange
        case LogLevel::RED:
            return "\033[31m"; // Red
        default:
            return "\033[0m"; // Reset color
        }
    }

public:
    Logger(const std::string& filename) {
        logFile.open(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    }

    ~Logger() {
        if (logFile.is_open()) {
            logFile.close();
        }
    }

    void log(LogLevel level, const std::string& message) {
        std::string color = getColorCode(level);

        // Print to console with color
        std::cout << getTimestamp() << " " << color << message << "\033[0m" << std::endl;

        // Write to file
        if (logFile.is_open()) {
            logFile << getTimestamp() << " " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void trace(const std::string& message) {
        log(LogLevel::GREY, message);
    }

    void debug(const std::string& message) {
        log(LogLevel::BLUE, message);
    }

    void info(const std::string& message) {
        log(LogLevel::GREEN, message);
    }

    void warn(const std::string& message) {
        log(LogLevel::YELLOW, message);
    }

    void error(const std::string& message) {
        log(LogLevel::ORANGE, message);
    }

    void critical(const std::string& message) {
        log(LogLevel::RED, message);
    }
};
```
````

Comment: Note- I haven't added systems like file logging yet.

Comment: Youtube just suggested me a video from a chanel called TheCherno. Since you are starting to learn coding and are particularly interested in game development, you might want to check it out. Happy coding!!!. https://www.youtube.com/@TheCherno

Comment: Don't write your own logger. Here is a simple one I use. https://github.com/emilk/loguru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does not need a lot of review. You are following most best practices. But, here are a few suggestions. I dont know of any text editors that support colors like this, but you can always use `less` or `cat`.

1. You dont need to explicitly close the file. `std::ofstream` does that for you.
2. Add a filename and line number variable to your functions. You can then wrap the function logger functions in a macro and pass **FILE** and **LINE** to these variables. This way you can log the location of your messages too.
3. Provide `operator<<` overloads for the logger class. Sometimes it is easier to stream messages, specially if they have variables in them.
4. If you are doing C++20, consider support for `std::format`.
5. Consider using std::chrono for time.

Comment: Even better than `FILE` and `LINE`: since C++20 you can use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

Comment: Should I be using C++ 20 cause right now I'm using c++ 17 are there any significant changes i should be aware of before switching?

Comment: Since you are just starting now, I does not matter as much. Yes C++20 has a lot of changes. A lot of them are to the parts of the language that is fairly advanced. For begineers, I would say the error messages are nicer.